# Not able to call GET REST URL with Path Variable

Tags: rest, jmeter, path-variables

I have Sample REST Endpoint with Path Variable parameter as argument.

http://localhost:8080/DempAppication/v1/users/John

I'm calling the same with JMeter and setting it like below

Server Name or IP : localhost
Path : /DempAppication/v1/users

and adding parameters like
name :  John

After running it , i can see my Endpoint URL is creating like

http://localhost:8080/DempAppication/v1/users?name=John

But I am not using Query Param , instead I am using path Param.

How can i set it , so that my endpoint will be exact path param?

Answer (score 0):

You stated it's part of the path, so add it as is to Path field

```
/DempAppication/v1/users/John
```

without adding John parameter